# Power BI - How to view zeros in the matrix table visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently building a report in Power BI. I added a matrix table along with its data. The matrix table just consist of sums per column (shown below).

[image]

There are multiple of slicers I have for the report. The problem is when I start filtering, the data disappears from the matrix. Instead of disappearing, I want it those values to be zero.

I have already used the measure: `IF(ISBLANK(SUM(COUNT)), 0, SUM(COUNT)` And it still did not work (shown below). What should I do so that the zeroes would appear on the matrix table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need for this approach to work

1. You need your Categories in a separate table to the rest of your data (joined by category ID) - if you don't have an ID, you can get away with Category name). You can build this table in DAX with something like `CategoryTable = DISTINCT(MyData[CategoryName])`. This new table and your data table need to be linked with a relationship. On your visual, use the Category from the Categories table and the measure you have created.
2. Make sure "Show items with no data" is checked on the matrix's fields. [image]